# Is it possible to the read data from bytea type field using getBlob() method in postgresql9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, jdbc-odbc, pg-jdbc

I am using `postgresql 9.2` and ,when I read the data from `Bytea`(used to store binary large object data in `postgresql)` field using `getBlob()` method but I'm getting the same error

```
Error: type bad value for long.
```

I know that I'm getting this error because of only `getBinaryStream()` and `getBytes()` method works with this(Bytea) and `getBlob()` method works with `OID` type field. But I have situation.So I would like to know that, is there any way to read the data from `Bytea` using `getBlob()` method in `Postgresql9.2` . Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show your code and the table definition please - edit the question to add the appropriate info (and read the formatting info while you're at it).

Comment: @Craig Ringer                                                  Table definition is: create table test(data bytea);                and if i'm using setBinaryStream() method to writing serialized object data into data field. when I am using getBinaryStream() or getBytes() method to read data from data field then it's ok but i want to read data using getBlob() method...

Comment: In future please *edit the question* to add things like table definitions, way easier to read. Anyway - I strongly suspect `getBlob()` expects you to have a `lo`, which is really an oid pointing to `pg_largeobject`. Take a look at the PgJDBC sources.

Comment: @Craig Ringer thank you..I got my answer

Comment: For Postgresql9.2 which one is the best(for performance,memory,speed of accessing) method to read data from bytea field, getBinaryStream() or getBytes() for same scenario?

Comment: Test and see. Personally expect `getBytes()` because PgJDBC doesn't currently support streaming `bytea` so it always reads the whole thing into memory anyway.

Comment: @Craig Ringer  thank you so much to you, i got my answer and now i am going to use getBytes()